# Goal Oriented Programming: Minimizing maximum percentage deviation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

I am interested formulating a Multi-Objective Linear Program, that minimizes the maximum percentage deviation.

To make the matters more concrete, consider two maximisation problems, max(c1*x|x∈X) and max(c2*x|x∈X) which have an optimal value of v1 and v2 respectively (predetermined).

Here is what I thought, yet I am not sure of it, given I lack the proper background in linear programming.

```
Min O
Subject to
           O ≥ (v1 - c1*x)/v1   
           O ≥ (v2 - c2*x)/v2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

$$
\begin{align}
\min_{x,d_i}\>&\sum_i w_i d_i\\
      &d_i = \frac{v_i - c_i x}{v_i}\\
      &\text{constraints on $x$} 
\end{align}
$$
where $d_i\ge 0$ are additional decision variables and $w$ are weights (constants).